# Is it possible to have 2 inbound endpoints with 1 number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have 2 inbounds in my project, one is for client and second is employee

1. /api/client/inbound
2. /api/employee/inbound

I want somehow to send messages from one phone number. Is it possible to differ answers and depends answer send to proper inbound endpoint, or I should buy 2 numbers for that?

Answer (score 1):

Point your number to maybe /api/router, have that code figure out where it should go, and then pass back a  to the appropriate URL.